# Force child classes to implement protocol swift

Tags: swift

How can i forced a child class to implement a protocol declared in the parent class?

I tried this:

```
protocol MyProtocol {
    var myVar : String { get }
}

class ParentClass: MyProtocol {
    var myVar = "parent"
}

class ChildClass: ParentClass {
}
```

But my child class doesn't force me to override myVar.

This is possible ?

Thank you very much,

Morgan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as my knowledge this is not possible in Swift. If you try conforming to the parent class's protocol, Leads to an error "Cannot override with a stored property". Since the protocol is already conformed in the parentClass.

```
protocol MyProtocol {
    var myVar : String { get  }
}

class ParentClass: MyProtocol {
    var myVar = "parent"

}

class ChildClass: ParentClass {
    var myVar = "hello"
    // Throws compilation error, "Cannot override with a stored property" since it's already conformed by the parentClass itself.
}
```

Added:

In general words multi-level implementation of an interface is not possible, In iOS words  protocol's should be implemented at single level only. But since you've inherited the parentClass, childClass has the scope to access parentClass members.

```
class ChildClass: ParentClass, MyProtocol {
    func printValue(){
        println("newvalue : \(myVar)")
        myVar = "hello"
    }

}
```

Hope this helps...!

Comment: Yes it's throws a compilation error. So i have to add my protocol in my child classes declaration?

Comment: class ChildClass: ParentClass, MyProtocol { }, It's again has the same effect, will throw the same error.

Comment: Read the "Added" part of my post. After reading it, If you want to access both parentClass members and wants to implement the MyProtocol members, then it's not possible. But, you can do either of the above, but not both.

Answer (score 13):

Swift does not have such feature.

All you can do is, emitting the runtime error. And you have to use [computed property](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Properties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH14-XID_386) to override the property.

Something like this:

```
protocol MyProtocol {
    var myVar : String { get }
}

class ParentClass: MyProtocol {
     var myVar:String {
        if self.dynamicType !== ParentClass.self {
            fatalError("subclass must implement myVar")
        }
        return "parent"
     }
}

class ChildClass1: ParentClass {
    override var myVar:String {
        return "hello"
    }
}

class ChildClass2: ParentClass {
    // missing myVar implementation
}

let parent = ParentClass()
parent.myVar // -> "parent"

let child1 = ChildClass1()
child1.myVar // -> "hello"

let child2 = ChildClass2()
child2.myVar // -> fatal error: subclass must implement myVar
```

Comment: This is the most appropriate answer I have found :) Hence +1

Answer (score -1):

My approach to dealing with this is to include the delegate parameter in the class initializer.  See the code below:

```
protocol ProtocolExample {
    func somethingNeedsToHappen()
}

// typical class example with delegate property for the required protocol
class ClassExampleA {
    
    var delegate: ProtocolExample!
    
    init() {
    }
    
    func aCriticalMethodWithUpdates() {
        delegate.somethingNeedsToHappen()
    }
}

// use class example in a view controller.  Can easily forget to invoke the delegate and protocol
class MySampleViewControllerA: UIViewController {
    
    var classExampleA : ClassExampleA!
    
    func loadMyData() {
        classExampleA = ClassExampleA()
    }
}

// an alternative approach for the class is to include the delegate parameter in the initializer.
class ClassExampleB {
    
    var delegate: ProtocolExample!
    
    init(delegateForUpdates: ProtocolExample) {
        delegate = delegateForUpdates
    }
    
    func doSomething() {
        delegate.somethingNeedsToHappen()
    }
}

// go to use it and you're reminded that the parameter is required...
class MySampleViewControllerB: UIViewController {
    
    var classExampleB: ClassExampleB!
    
    func loadMyData() {
        classExampleB = ClassExampleB() // error: Missing argument for parameter 'delegateForUpdates' in call
    }
}

// so to avoid error:
class MySampleViewControllerC: UIViewController {
    
    var classExampleB: ClassExampleB!
    
    func loadMyData() {
        classExampleB = ClassExampleB(delegateForUpdates: <#ProtocolExample#>)
    }
}
```