# iOS Swift 3 Architecture issue

Tags: ios, swift, architecture

I'm trying to find the best solution for a recurrent problem I have, which I solved differently each time.

Imagine I have a form in several steps ( let say 2 to begin )

My code structure is :

```
class SuperStepViewController: UIViewController {

  //Some generic Stuff

    func continueAction(sender : AnyObject?) {
        //NOTHING
    }
}


class Step1ViewController: SuperStepViewController { 

    override func continueAction(sender : AnyObject?) {
        //DO SOME USEFULL STUFF
    }

}


class Step2ViewController: SuperStepViewController { 

    override func continueAction(sender : AnyObject?) {
        //DO SOME USEFULL STUFF
    }

}
```

What I want is to change this code, to not implement the `continueAction` function in the `SuperViewController`, because it has no default implementation.

At a first look, I thought `protocol` was a good idea. If I put `continueAction` in a required protocol, I will have a compilation-time error, which is what I want.

```
protocol StepProtocol {
    func continueAction()
} 

class SuperStepViewController: UIViewController {
    //GENERIC
}


class Step1ViewController: SuperStepViewController, StepProtocol { 

   func continueAction(sender : AnyObject?) {
        //DO SOME USEFULL STUFF
    }

}


class Step2ViewController: SuperStepViewController, StepProtocol { 

   func continueAction(sender : AnyObject?) {
        //DO SOME USEFULL STUFF
    }

}
```

But it is not enough, I want generate this compilation as soon as I subclass the superview controller. I know Java as something like Abstract class.

```
class Step3ViewController: SuperStepViewController { 

   //NO continueAction implementation => No compilation error

}
```

Did anyone have an idea ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Force child classes to implement protocol swift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27167685/force-child-classes-to-implement-protocol-swift)

Comment: I tried you're code out and it seems to work like you want. As soon as I subclass the SuperStepViewController and the StepProtocol, I'm told that it needs "continueAction"-function and suggests "internal func continueAction()". If I only subclass SuperStepViewController and not the protocol, I get no errors of course. Isn't this what you want?

Comment: No, i don't want explicitly extends the stepProtocol. but I think this is not possible after all

Answer (score 0):

No. This is not possible in Swift. Swift does not support such activity.